# How to fix "react-dom.development.js:287 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to upload my react forms to the state so I can fetch an API with those credentials

I have tried creating a function that looks like this:

```
handleEmail(event) {
    this.setState({email: event.target.value});
  }
  handlePassword(event) {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar />
        <form className="pt-6 container">
          <div className="form-group">
            <label className="mt-6" >Your email</label>
            <input name className="form-control" onChange={this.handleEmail} placeholder="Email" type="email" />
          </div> {/* form-group// */}
          <div className="form-group">
            <a className="float-right" href="#">Forgot?</a>
            <label>Your password</label>
            <input className="form-control" onChange={this.handlePassword} placeholder="******" type="password" />
          </div> {/* form-group// */}
```

Comment: There are *so many* questions about `this` being undefined; you need to bind it or use arrow functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scoping issue. Since these methods are being called after event triggers, the `this` points to scope from which it is called, rather than pointing to the class instance where it is defined.
You need to use arrow functions to fix this.

```
handleEmail = (event) => {
    this.setState({email: event.target.value});
  }
  handlePassword = (event) => {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your function, add the constructor like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        email: '',
        password:''
    };

    this.handleEmail= this.handleEmail.bind(this);
    this.handlePassword= this.handlePassword.bind(this);
}
```